# Cascading Select in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

I need too show a dropdown box onto the selection of option in another dropdown box. For eg. if I select "USA" in one of the dropdown box then the other dropdown box should show cities related to USA like Newyork, San Diego etc. How can i achieve this is AngularJS?

Comment: Hope this will help you! http://codepen.io/AliAdravi/pen/vObeya

Comment: This example may help you. http://jsfiddle.net/rcjWu/